# How to clone tabpage in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabpage

I have a tabpage contains two panels and these panels contain datagridview and buttons. I want to clone selected tabPage without cell values when double-clicked on any cell. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code I've tried. This code does not clone panels, datagridview and buttons.

```
TabPage tpOld = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
TabPage tpNew = new TabPage();
foreach (Control c in tpOld.Controls)
{
    Control cNew = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());

    PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(c);

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor entry in pdc)
    {
        object val = entry.GetValue(c);
        entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
    }

    // add control to new TabPage
    tpNew.Controls.Add(cNew);
}

tpNew.Text = cellValue;
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tpNew;
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tpNew);
```

Comment: Cloning controls cannot work reliably, they have entirely too much runtime state.  A simple workaround is to just move the control when a new tab is selected.  Just change its Parent property.  Or use a UserControl.

Comment: I created a new tabpage by using Visual Studio Designer and I dynamically added or removed this tabpage. My problem has been solved.